# Phone keeps restarting / shutting down randomly is there any logging to help debugging

Tags: reboot, samsung-europa

Sometimes my Samsung Europa restarts itself when it's on standby.

Does Android have any logging which I can access to see what caused the restart?

I have installed a few apps from the Android app market and some games. Haven't installed anything that I've developed myself.

Answer (score 2):

You can install "Log Collector" from the android market, it's free. It can email the logcat to an email address. I am not sure whether the log clears or not if there is a reboot though. You should be able to see something in there regardless.

Comment: Is it possible with Android 6 on phone without root access?